# scheduledTimer not firing if I navigate to two viewcontrollers

Tags: swift, timer

I have a weak scheduledTimer:

```swift
weak var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timerInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fire), userInfo: ["id",id], repeats: false)
```

If I begin this timer and navigate to only one viewController, it will fire in the background with no issue. However, if I navigate to a second viewController before the timer fires, it will never go off. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: maybe because it's weak?

Comment: I tried removing weak, but that caused it to not clear after navigating to only one viewController. Making it weak makes sense though, right? It clears from memory more easily?

Comment: Didn't understand the navigation hierarchy you're following here. Kindly clarify.

Comment: tasksTableVc ---> TaskInfoVc ----> EditTaskInfoVc

Assuming the timer is weak, I can navigate to TaskInfoVc and they will fire no problem. The issue is when I go to EditTaskInfoVc before the timers fire. They will no longer do so.

Comment: remove weak, implement deinit in ViewController with timer, inside timer?.invalidate()

Comment: In which controller are you having the Timer?

Comment: @PGDev tasksTableVc

Comment: Add more code when and where you're firing the timer.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik The use of `weak` is not a problem. Please read the first paragraph of the Timer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

- To define

```
class viewController: UIViewController 
{
  var timer = Timer()
```

- use in other function

```
   func one()
    {
        timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(backClick), userInfo: ["id"], repeats: false)
    }

    func two()
    {
        timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(backClick), userInfo: ["id"], repeats: false)
    }
```

- `inValidate()` timer

```
  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
     timer.fire()
  }
```

Comment: I'm using `Main.storyboard`, so I'm not seguing programatically. Also, the timer wouldn't be in the scope of whatever function I would need to do that in anyways.

Comment: How do I access the timers if I created them in a different function?

Comment: define timer in class function globally

Comment: So you can access it anywhere in the class

Comment: If I define it globally I cannot run it after a delay later though, as I can only use timer.fire() which does it immediately

Comment: If you define it globally in the class then you can fire or invalidate whenever you want in class function, or when class did load or class desappear.

Comment: I understand that I can fire or invalidate it whenever I want in the class, but if I want to run it with a `timeInterval` delay, I can no longer do that, right?

Comment: You can use it with interval and delay multiple times in multiple function whenever you want

Comment: Okay, when I define it globally, what do I write? `weak var timer: ???`

Also, how do I do the equivalent of:
`weak var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timerInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fire), userInfo: ["id",id], repeats: false)`
wherever I want?

Comment: It did not work. If I do not put `weak timer: Timer()` it never fires. If I add `weak`, the first task will fire, but not the others.

Comment: But you've to define as timer = Timer() not as timer: Timer()

Comment: Tried the updated answer, it causes nothing to get cleared after navigating to the second viewcontroller.

Answer (score -2):

Because of that was weak like @Alexandr Kolesnik 's comment, or may be you invalidated when first one is disappeared.

Comment: I tried removing weak, but that caused it to not clear after navigating to only one viewController. Making it weak makes sense though, right? It clears from memory more easily?

Comment: From the first paragraph of the Timer documentation: *"Timers work in conjunction with run loops. Run loops maintain strong references to their timers, so you don’t have to maintain your own strong reference to a timer after you have added it to a run loop."*. From the documentation for the `scheduledTimer` method: *"Creates a timer and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode."*.

Comment: How would I fix the issue then? I have been trying @wolverian's method with little luck.